# Provide git credentials to fastlane/cocoapods

Tags: ios, jenkins, cocoapods, fastlane

I am trying to run the iOS build using `fastlane` which uses `cocoapods` through Jenkins. But its failing at `pod install` step because there is no credentials configured in the file.

How can I pass git credentials stored in Jenkins through command line to `fastlane`/`cocoapods`

Comment: If you have private pods, can't you configure the Podfile to use those credentails. Even better add the jenkis ssh key to the git tool you're using (github/gitlab etc).

Comment: I have added local jenkins ssh key to github. but it still asks for `Username for 'https://github.com':` & `Password for 'https://github.com':`

Comment: Then I think you have something else wrong in the configs. It shouldn't ask for credentials of github. Make sure you're repo is added using ssh not http maybe.

Comment: This was the issue, fixed now. thanks

Comment: Can you tell me how you fixed this issue. I am facing this issue.